# How to disable original img title when using qtip

Tags: jquery, image, attributes, title, qtip

I am using jquery 1.4.2 and qtip-1.0.js

in ie/7/6/8 whenever I hover over the image on which the tooltip is applied, I get the tooltip... but I also do get the original title... does not happen on the firefox though...
Is there any option or setting specific to disable the img titl and just show the tooltip?

my code looks like this

```
$('.selector img[title]').qtip({style: {name: 'green'},
                tip: true
},
              show: { delay: 100 },
              hide: { delay: 100 }
            });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On images, IE will create a tooltip with the "alt" value, not the "title", so you'll need to remove the "alt" attribute as well.

Comment: well... I was just trying the alt attribute as I am seeing your answer and it is looking good for now... Thank you ! That answered my question and hrs I spent on this today!! Thanks!

Comment: hmm... looks like I red your answer way to fast. I did not remove the alt or title attribute... but I used the alt attribute of images to pull up the qtip, and it works fine, but now when I am trying to have a qtip on the links, it is giving me the original title as well.. and help on that? removing the attributes after applying the qtip results in empty qtips

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `.removeAttr('title')` after calling `.qtip`.

Comment: Thanks for the fastest reply ever... :) but did not work...
after making this change, the tooltip appears emppty ... so may be it needs reads it from the title attribute?